# Separate single database into active and archive

Tags: mysql, sql, backup

I have a single database, most of the tables are connected in some way. 
It consists of over 500000 records. 
I need to implement live search, but number of records bothers me.

Database will grow and live search in millions of records will sure cause problems. So i need to move old records (let's assume date field is present) to another database and only keep fresh ones available for search.

Old records won't be used anymore, that's for sure, but i still need to keep them.

Any ideas how that could be implemented in MySQL?

Comment: That's generally a bad idea in my experience; appropriate indexes and search criteria should narrow down the searched records such that the number of records (except in extreme cases) should not be that much of a factor. It might not be a bad idea, except for that that _"old records won't be used anymore"_ almost always turns out to be false when _"but i still need to keep them"_ is attached to it; and then you end up having to search two (or more) places.

Comment: @Uueerdo, _"but i still need to keep them"_ means in case of lawsuit. They won't be needed for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

500,000 records really is not very many records.

Before you start taking drastic actions (such as limiting the ability of users to seamlessly see all the data at once), you should consider basics for improving performance:

- Indexes to improve standard query performance.
- Partitioning to limit the portions of tables that need to be accessed.
- Full text indexing to improve `match()` queries.
- Optimization of SQL queries.

In general, these are sufficient for databases that are orders of magnitude larger than the volume you are dealing with.

These may not apply to your particular situation; but you should exhaust the lower-hanging fruit for performance optimization before changing your physical data model for a problem that might never occur.

Comment: i'm not sure if db server can take it when live search is on, it's computing power is quite limited.